# How can I integrate Sencha ExtJs Web App in SalesForce?

Tags: integration, website-integration, salesforce-sencha

My web application is developed using open source JavaScript libraries such as Sencha ExtJs, Jquery, Openlayers etc. The application have dashboards, Charts, Grids & map (currently working with dummy data). At first level, I need to integrate the application inside a SalesForce's Tab. I am very beginner to SaleForce. Kindly help...

Thanks

Mohammed Shafeek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple way is to use web tabs

Here are steps:

1) Go to setup -> create -> tabs
2) In web tabs section click new
3) complete the wizard
4) Make sure you provide URL of your application
5) At the end on Wizard your tab is ready

This will just add iFrame and the page will not be able to interact with SFDC

If you want the interaction then you will need to convert your app as Canvas

Comment: Thanks @AtulRajguru its really a good start for me. My application needs SalesForce data access. So, How can I convert the app as Canvas? using Heroku?. If I deployed the App in Heroku, How can I integrate this in SalesForce?

Comment: i think you should play with canvas first and then decide on how you can deployed the App in Heroku.

Comment: This will help you to ger stared http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/platform_connect/canvas_framework.pdf